# remove whitespace inside json object key value pair

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to use `trim()` for json key value pair , but it seems not to work, can anyone please help ?

```
var user = { first_name: "CSS",
  last_name: "  H ",
  age: 41,
  website: "java2s.com"
};

for (var key in user) {
  console.log((key+"-->"+user[key].trim());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the trimmed value to the specific `user[key]`:

```js
var user = { first_name: "CSS", last_name: " H ", age: 41, website: "java2s.com" };

for (var key in user) {
    user[key] = user[key].toString().trim()
    console.log(key+"-->"+user[key]);
}
```

Also, if you cannot use `.trim()` because of older browsers, use a [**polyfill**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) for that.

## Recommended:

```
function trim(string) {
    return string.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
};
```

## Evil edition:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
    String.prototype.trim = function () {
        return this.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
    };
}
```

Comment: Please test code before uploading it. Edit: Better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll do my best next time!

Answer (score 1):

That's because you can't access a `JSON` value like:

```
var value = json[key]; // Wrong
```

You must do it like this:

```
var value = json.key; // Correct
```

Comment: He is iterating the object, meaning that he has to use array index instead of the property.

Answer (score 1):

All browsers since IE9+ have trim()

For those browsers who does not support trim(), you can use this polyfill from MDN:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
(function() {
    // Make sure we trim BOM and NBSP
    var rtrim = /^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g;
    String.prototype.trim = function() {
        return this.replace(rtrim, '');
    };
})();
```

}